# *Those police* or *That police*

Tags: pronouns

I know that *police* is always plural, but when it comes to which pronouns to use with it, is it also considered plural, that is, do we use *these* and *those* woth it?

I suppose it'd be better to just use *those policemen* instead.

I haven't found any other question about which pronouns to use with *police*.

1. Look, [those/that] police are trying to catch us!
2. [These/this] police are working harder than the previous ones.

Comment: I've a feeling "those police officers", "those policemen" if they were all men, or similar would be more usual if you're indicating/picking out about particular people in uniform (rather than police in general or as a whole).

Comment: Yes - _police_ refers to the organisation. We wouldn't call an individual officer 'a police'.

Comment: Isn't "police" usually singular? "I've spoken to the police", "the police quickly arrived on the scene", etc.

Comment: Also, your examples both use the word 'police are...' If you use the word 'are,' you have to automatically use those/these, or some other plural pronoun

Comment: So, does it turn out that I cannot use any demonstratives with *police* on its own, and I have say *those police officers*?

Comment: @Showsni Your examples aren't indicative. e.g. "I've spoken to the acrobats" & "The acrobats arrived quickly" are both plural. -- For singular/plural determination, you typically either want to look at acceptability with a/an (e.g. "A police arrived quickly" is wrong), or you want to look at number concord with a verb (e.g. "The police are here." not "The police is here." ).

Comment: 'Police' is a very unusual 'quasi-count noun' (10 000 police were ...' but '*3 police were'. It is singular in form (and countifies, taking a plural, 'the polices [= constabularies] of several counties'). It takes, however, a plural verb form ('Police were yesterday searching ...'. I'd say it's etically countable (6 policemen ...). // I suppose '7 members of the Sterrytown Police were ...' is the best way to handle such phrases.

Answer (score 2):

Those police is informal but correct.

That policeman is singular.

Those police officers were tall.

Answer (score 2):

When you say *I've spoken to the police* or *the police arrived,* the noun refers to the organisation in general, even though only one or a few individual officers were involved in the situation. We never say *these/those police* to refer to a particular group of police officers.

Comment: It's a travesty to compare out-of-state police forces to our hometown heroes: these police here are fine upstanding citizens; those police there are nothing but stooges and crooks. (Or substitute whether opinion you happen to hold, but *these* and *those* work fine in context.